# Azure Function - Change the name of the variable "code"

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-functions

According the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook) the HttpTrigger API Key has the variable name `code`, like this:

```
https://<yourapp>.azurewebsites.net/api/<function>?code=<ApiKey>
```

Can I change this variable name? In my case I want to change it to `access_token` like this:

```
https://<yourapp>.azurewebsites.net/api/<function>?access_token=<ApiKey>
```

I want to do this because I want to use Azure Functions together with a 3rd party webhook that is expects `access_token` as the variable name.

Comment: You can set up API Management as the gateway to your Azure Function, have it accept access_token and use a policy to convert that to a call to the Azure Function with code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that name cannot be changed - it is part of our API and isn't configurable.

Comment: Not the answer I had hoped for, but thank you for the answer. Also there seems to be a work-around in the comment from @Saca above.